# Python - Adding newline feed into a Loop that reads an array

Tags: python, arrays, newline

I am using python to run a loop to read an array and print the results. I can get the results to print but they come back like this. `IWBBPB00210IWBBPA00065`. When it should look like this

```
IWBBPB00210
IWBBPA00065
```

Here is my code.

```
with open('Count_BB_Serial_weekly.json', 'r') as lowfile:
  low = json.load(lowfile)

low1 = low["total_serials"]
low3 = ""

low2 = low["serials"]
for i in range(len(low2)):
    #print(low2[i])
    low3 += low2[i]

print(low3)
```

When I originally printed low2[i] it would come back how I want but later on I have to send this in a message and in the message it would only send the last value from low2. I have tried adding `'\n'` to the end of low3 but this does not work.

How do I properly add this new line feed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The newline character is `'\n'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to loop through a list is:

```
for i in low2:
   low3 += i
```

A still more Pythonic way is not to loop at all:

```
low3 = '\n'.join(low2)
```

The latter incidentally solves your newline problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `print()` function appends newline by default. To construct the string by yourself, you can append the `\n` character to the string:

```
for i in range(len(low2)):
    #print(low2[i])
    low3 += low2[i] + '\n'

print(low3)
```

But as long as you have all the lines in the list `low2`, you can simply join it with the `\n` char:

```
'\n'.join(low2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. But I believe you want a line break. You can archive that by adding '\n'

```
with open('Count_BB_Serial_weekly.json', 'r') as lowfile:
  low = json.load(lowfile)

  low1 = low["total_serials"]
  low3 = ""

  low2 = low["serials"]
  for i in range(len(low2)):
    #print(low2[i])
    low3 += low2[i] + '\n'

print(low3)
```